# python search through text files composed of lines

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hid = '282'
    b = (hid)+"\n"
    hidtext = [open("foo.txt").readlines()]
    r = str (b) in hidtext
    print hidtext
    print r
    print (hid)
    print b
```

on above code i want to search for the "hid" value , however i am getting false on "r" although "282" does exist.

here is the output , foo is a text file with number in new lines.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/Dropbox/pycharm/win3.py 
[['282\n', '777\n', '418\n']] 
False 
282 
282
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Get rid of the extra square brackets around `open`, or use `str(b) in hidtext[0]`.

Comment: `readlines` will return you list always, why you have to put list again in list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets outside the `open("foo.txt").readlines()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hid = '282'
    b = (hid)+"\n"
    hidtext = open("foo.txt").readlines()
    r = str (b) in hidtext
    print hidtext
    print r
    print (hid)
    print b
```

---

Result:

```
['282\n', '777\n', '418\n']
True
282
282
```